# Angular2 JSON Mapper adds "Z" to datetime

Tags: angularjs, json, datetime, angular, mapping

I have a simple "post" call to the server to add a new item. When this item comes back and is mapped to my "item" object, the date strings all have added "Z" in the end, which makes all comparisons think that the objects are not equal.

```
 Model fields on the client:
         public dateModified: string;
         public dateCreate: string;

 Model fields on the server:
         public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
         public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }



 this.itemCRUDSevice.addItem(this.itemName)
            .subscribe(item=> {
                // Item here has now "Z" added to the date strings
            }

 WebAPI returns:
 dateCreated : "2016-09-19T16:21:02.1257955"
 dateModified : "2016-09-19T16:21:02.1257955"

 Item after subscription
 dateCreated : "2016-09-19T16:21:02.1257955Z"  <<<< Z
 dateModified : "2016-09-19T16:21:02.1257955Z" <<<< Z
```

Is there some option / locale settings I am missing somewhere for this not to happen?

Comment: What you get is a standard ISO string for representing an instant. The Z means "UTC". And it probably comes from your server JSON serialization, not from angular. What is the concrete problem? I don't see any comparison anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: I am using deep equals plugin on NPM to do the comparison. The problem is that when the response comes back with my object, the date strings all have "Z" in them. I could manually remove it, but I want a better solution. My CRUD returns an Observable<Item>, and when I do .subscribe, the "item" now contains "Z" in it's date strings.